# My absolute positioned particles.js is covering my relative div

Tags: html, css, vue.js

https://codepen.io/AnonymousCaptain/pen/MWavMWm

```html
<div class="outer-container">                  
  <div id="particles-js">
    <div class="your-content">
          <article id="3" class="bg-dusk transition md:group-hover:opacity-50 md:hover:opacity-important md:hover:scale-11/10x my-8">
            <h3 class="mt-8 text-lg font-semibold leading-tight text-zenith">3</h3>
            <p class="mt-8">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et suspendisse mauris molestie, libero wisi a nulla, laoreet dolor tortor orci, amet debitis enim ultricies fermentum.</p>
          </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me fix the overlap. Besides that... I would to know if you think I should switch to a Vue based particles component instead?

Comment: Hi Robotica. To understand better how absolute and relative positioning works, you may take a look at [this article from w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp).
To help here on SO, I recommend you to reduce your codepen example to the minimum code necessary to replicate the issue. Otherwise it's difficult to locate the problem.

Comment: improved HTML formatting and converted to snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#particles-js {
  position: relative;
}
```

Will fix it.
But as recommended by Uchendu... way to much code in the example..